# Sharing large data between threads without locks

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm learning C# (currently use .NET Framework 2.0). Writing a test program that should compare images. First, I read all images and make an array of thumbnails of these images. Then I run multiple threads to work with this array. Threads must select a single object from the array and compare it with others. But I got Exception "The object is currently in use elsewhere". It seems that Bitmap has an internal lock that prevents access to an object from multiple threads even for reading. If I lock "compare" function what's the point even have multiple threads? I can copy array of thumbnails for each thread, but I do not think it's a good idea because an array may be big and also it's an inefficient use of resources. So, my question is: How threads can work with shared (potentially large) data without locking?

Comment: What bitmap? If that isa UI level bitmap (WIndows FOrms) it can only be manipulated by the thread that created it - this is a design decision for UI elements in Windows.

Comment: "How threads can work with shared (potentially large) data without locking?" - they can work correctly (if data is immutable or very carefully partitioned between threads) or incorrectly producing random results in all other cases... Not sure what exactly is your problem - you pick object that is designed to protect its data from cross-thread access (which is easy way to have thread safety) but asking seemingly general question (i.e. immutable array of integers can be shared easily)...

Comment: See "Thread Synchronization" for GDI+: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533801%28VS.85%29.aspx. I suspect this message relates to "ObjectBusy" from that paragraph

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov GDI+ is a bit more nuanced than an `int[]`, though

Comment: @TomTom actually that's not quite true; GDI+ has slightly different threading semantics

Comment: @TomTom No, it's not UI level bitmap, I don't show any images in UI.